# Remove padding of content view in UITableViewCell though storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to remove the default padding of content view in `UITableViewCell`?

I put two label in the `UITableViewCell`'s content view, The content view has a gray background color.

when I set top margin space between title and the content view to 0 (via constraint), the title is not align to the top!!! The same is leading and trailing space.

[image: padding of content view in UITableCell]

Here is my view struct:

[image]

I googled a lot, the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769184/remove-padding-on-uitableviewcell) works by overriding the `layoutSubviews` of UITableViewCell and setting frame of title manually.

But can I do it in story board? or it there a attribute or something that controls the padding of the content view????

Comment: Are you referring to the section headers/footers or?

Comment: Yeah, I set heights for header/footer in section to 0, but nothing changes

Comment: Do you need the titles at all? If you remove the titles it should change. Are you testing only in simulator or on device as well?

Comment: No, I remove the title, but there still a padding around the footer. I only test it on simulator, does the content view has a padding attributions or something?

Comment: I can't say I have had this problem. Usually when I remove the section header it disappears. I never use footers while using a header. I will run a test and get back to you.

Comment: It is just a demo, the footer is something like subtitle

Comment: I have added an answer. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a checkbox labeled "Constrain to margins" in the popup where you specify constraints. I suspect you left it checked. Margins default to 8 points, which may explain what you are seeing.

Here is a better answer with screenshots:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755511/4122965

Comment: Oh!!! That works!!! I usually add constrains by control-drag the view to another, that little popup does not have a checkbox. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'd love to be able to +10 !