# UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator remove right margin

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I use autolayout `UITableViewCell` for dynamic cell height introduced in iOS 8.
I set up my cell and set `accessoryType` as `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`. I do all layout programatically.

I tried do this:
`self.layoutMargin = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` inside `UITableViewCell` in `init` method

[image]

I want to remove right margin or set custom value with contentView resizing

Comment: Take a look at the answer in this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755451/what-is-the-reason-for-the-remaining-vertical-spacing-between-an-inner-view-an/26755511#26755511

Comment: @GurtejSingh I tried this solution, but it doesn't work for because I do my layout programatically use PureLayout.

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer below. Please see if it works now.

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If yes, then you should accept it (click the checkmark below the voting buttons in my answer) please let me know if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added code for managing the frame of the textLabel and the detailTextLabel as well.

You can achieve this by overriding the `layoutSubViews` method in your custom cell class (if you are not using one, then create one first and use it in your table view). Add the following code to your table view cell class .m file:

```
const int ACCESORY_MARGIN = -10;
const int LABEL_MARGIN = -10;

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame;
    frame = self.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x += LABEL_MARGIN;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * LABEL_MARGIN;
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x += LABEL_MARGIN;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * LABEL_MARGIN;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;

    if (self.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        float estimatedAccesoryX = MAX(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x + self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x + self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width);

        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if (subview != self.textLabel &&
                subview != self.detailTextLabel &&
                subview != self.backgroundView &&
                subview != self.contentView &&
                subview != self.selectedBackgroundView &&
                subview != self.imageView &&
                subview.frame.origin.x > estimatedAccesoryX) {
                frame = subview.frame;
                frame.origin.x -= ACCESORY_MARGIN;
                subview.frame = frame;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Change the constants defined above to suit your needs.

Hope this helps and solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I create a test project and add your code. The results are next, accessory moved right, labels stay the same width and positions as before

Comment: Well, the code is working as expected. You never mentioned in your question that you want to move the labels too. Please update your question accordingly and I will update the answer. Thanks